# Kafka Spring boot offset reset?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

what is the main purpose of `auto-offset-reset: latest` and `enable-auto-commit: false` in Kafka consumers.

Is there a way in Kafka consumer I can check if I am able to receive the duplicate record or process the previous record during KafkaListner

What are all the necessary things to keep in mind while creating the Consumer side in spring boot and all the important things for logging, so that logging will have a meaning

Answer (score 1):

> purpose of `auto-offset-reset: latest`

To start at the end of the topic rather than the beginning

> ... and `enable-auto-commit: false`

So that your client (Spring) manages (or not) the offsets of the consumer rather than automatically every 500 messages, by default.

RE: duplicates - You will need to store all your records persistently somewhere else (in-memory or a database) in order to properly detect or process duplicates / previous offsets without rewinding the consumer via a seek method.

Adequate logging should be setup by Spring Boot by default.